# Delete "Comment" and "Share" buttons from Adobe Reader X toolbar

Tags: adobe-reader, toolbar

Is it possible to delete "Comment" and "Share" buttons from "Adobe Reader X"'s toolbar?  My screen is very-small (netbook) and I want to have some useful buttons on it, not the buttons I'll never use.

After I enabled all buttons I use, the "Comment and Share" part is not hidden and this part actually hides MY buttons, with "v" icon to access them. This is really annoying.

Comment: Even if I delete Comments plugins, the button is still in toolbar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Share" button is to be disabled as described here http://forums.adobe.com/thread/782577

> Create a key in registry

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Adobe\Acrobat Reader\10.0\Workflows] 
"bEnableAcrobatHS"=dword:00000000
```

Still no information about Comment button