# Hiding 'tools', 'comment' and 'sign' buttons in Adobe Reader XI

Tags: adobe-reader, pdf-reader

How can I hide 'tools', 'comment' and 'sign' **buttons** (note only the assosiated panes) from toolbar of Adobe Reader XI?

I found this, but did not work for me: http://blogs.adobe.com/acrolaw/2011/03/customizing-toolbars-in-acrobat-x-2/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove or prevent sidebar from opening by default on Adobe Reader](https://superuser.com/questions/902758/remove-or-prevent-sidebar-from-opening-by-default-on-adobe-reader)

Answer (score 14):

In adobe reader installation folder (typically C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Reader 11.0) 
Find the sub-folder Reader\Services.

Remove files "DEXEchoSign.spi" and "DEXShare.spi". (Adding .bak extension, or changing extension, is sufficient. Only renaming will not work.)

This removes the Tools and Share toolbar options.  I have not found a way to remove "Comment" yet.

This question is a duplicate of ([Delete "Comment" and "Share" buttons from Adobe Reader X toolbar](https://superuser.com/questions/321595/delete-comment-and-share-buttons-from-adobe-reader-x-toolbar)) but there seems to be a different answer accepted there.

Comment: Note to those trying it - removing DEXShare.spi didn't clear the Tool button until I clicked on it.  After that its disappearance seemed to persist.

Comment: Works for me. Had to remove something after a new "Open" button appeared in a new update (11.0.09) and I didn't have enough space while having the window at the half of my screen.

Comment: This only hide the `Share` button for me.

Answer (score 11):

I guess that annoys you the loading time of that right tools column. It annoys me too!

My solution is:
It is actually a toggle button.
Click again on the same Tools or Sign or Comment (i.e. the one highlighted) and it will hide it.

Now, the pdf will load faster. It is ok for me like that :)

Comment: Thanks, however my question is about hiding the buttons not the panes. When I resize the windows, those buttons hide the other useful buttons.

Answer (score 5):

1. Open a PDF in Acrobat Reader 2017
2. Toggle the right side pane that has Comment and Fill & Sign and More Tools so it is hidden
3. Open Edit menu then select Preferences
4. Select the Documents category
5. Tick the box "Remember current state of Tools Pane"
6. OK
7. Close the PDF

Adobe Acrobat 2017 will now remember the state of the Tools pane. It will be hidden the next time a PDF is viewed. To make it visible again toggle it to be visible before closing a PDF.

Tested in Adobe Acrobat Reader 2017 Version 2017.011.30065

Comment: Thanks. It's a great update. It seems not work for the "Navigation Pane Buttons" on the left of the screen. Any idea?

Comment: To control the behaviour of the left side panel when re-opening documents go to Edit > Preferences and enable "Restore last view settings when reopening documents". This does not affect the default of showing the Bookmarks pane. Perhaps Adobe will add an option to control the state of the left navigation menu in a future update.

Answer (score 2):

Press the first button labeled "Tools" again and it will be hidden.

Comment: Your answer doesn't completely answer the question.  Perhaps it should be a comment instead?

Answer (score 0):

Try pressing <kbd>F8</kbd> twice. It won't remove it, but it will hide it.

Answer (score 0):

Open a document and hide the tool, Fill&Sign, and Comment areas manually.
Edit | Preferences
Select Documents in the Category list.
Check the box: Restore last view setting when reopening documents

When you next open a document, those panes will not be opened by default.  Just keep them closed before you exit a document and all should be good.

Answer (score -1):

> `View > Show/Hide > Toolbar Items > Hide Toolbars`