# How to hide the Tool tab in Acrobat Reader?

Tags: pdf, adobe-reader

In Acrobat Reader, how to hide the Tool tab? Tool tab keeps reappearing all the time.

Of course by pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F4</kbd> it will hide, but how to do it permanently.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove or prevent sidebar from opening by default on Adobe Reader](http://superuser.com/questions/902758/remove-or-prevent-sidebar-from-opening-by-default-on-adobe-reader)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to Edit > Preferences (or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>) and under “Documents” section, uncheck “Open tools pane for each document”.

[image]