# Can I force Acrobat Reader (DC) to start without tools pane?

Tags: pdf, adobe-reader

How can I prevent Acrobat Reader from showing the Tools Pane when opening a PDF document?

This is when starting Acrobat Reader by opening a PDF document (as opposed to starting Acrobat Reader and then opening the document from within the program).

I know that Shift+F4 closes the Tools Pane, but I would like to not having to close it each and every time I open a document. I can't find a setting for changing the default.

I've tried to start the app, open a document, closing the tools pane, closing the document and then closing the app. Next time I open a document, the tools pane is visible again, which is not the behavior I desire.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove or prevent sidebar from opening by default on Adobe Reader](https://superuser.com/questions/902758/remove-or-prevent-sidebar-from-opening-by-default-on-adobe-reader)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you open the document, close the tool pane. Once closed, click on edit, then preferences. From there, click on Documents and then check Remember current state of Tool Pane.