# Windows 10 burn ISO?

Tags: windows, windows-10, dvd, iso-image, burning

How can I burn an ISO file to a DVD on Windows 10? The old tools don't exist any more. I need to make a new live Linux disc as my old ones are outdated with the drivers.

Comment: You should use the Media Creation Tool otherwise use Rufus after researching the correct settings for UEFI boot.

Answer (score 12):

The built-in tools **do** still exist.  If *"no such option is there,"* that means someone installed software within that specific Windows 10 configuration that changed the default `.iso` file type association.  As a result, you don't see the default capabilities to burn an `.iso` file to disc like you normally would.

Utilize the following code by pasting it into Notepad, saving it as a `.reg` file and merging it with admin privileges to restore your default file type association:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

; Created by: Shawn Brink
; http://www.tenforums.com
; Tutorial: http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/8703-default-file-type-associations-restore-windows-10-a.html


[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.iso]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.iso]
@="Windows.IsoFile"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.iso\OpenWithProgids]
"Windows.IsoFile"=""

[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SystemFileAssociations\.iso]

[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Windows.IsoFile]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Windows.IsoFile]
@="Disc Image File"
"FriendlyTypeName"=hex(2):40,00,25,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,52,\
  00,6f,00,6f,00,74,00,25,00,5c,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,33,00,\
  32,00,5c,00,73,00,68,00,65,00,6c,00,6c,00,33,00,32,00,2e,00,64,00,6c,00,6c,\
  00,2c,00,2d,00,33,00,30,00,36,00,30,00,32,00,00,00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Windows.IsoFile\DefaultIcon]
@=hex(2):25,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,52,00,6f,00,6f,00,74,00,25,\
  00,5c,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,33,00,32,00,5c,00,69,00,6d,00,\
  61,00,67,00,65,00,72,00,65,00,73,00,2e,00,64,00,6c,00,6c,00,2c,00,2d,00,35,\
  00,32,00,30,00,35,00,00,00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Windows.IsoFile\shell]
@="mount"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Windows.IsoFile\shell\burn]
"MUIVerb"=hex(2):40,00,25,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,52,00,6f,00,\
  6f,00,74,00,25,00,5c,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,33,00,32,00,5c,\
  00,69,00,73,00,6f,00,62,00,75,00,72,00,6e,00,2e,00,65,00,78,00,65,00,2c,00,\
  2d,00,33,00,35,00,31,00,00,00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Windows.IsoFile\shell\burn\command]
@=hex(2):25,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,52,00,6f,00,6f,00,74,00,25,\
  00,5c,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,33,00,32,00,5c,00,69,00,73,00,\
  6f,00,62,00,75,00,72,00,6e,00,2e,00,65,00,78,00,65,00,20,00,22,00,25,00,31,\
  00,22,00,00,00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Windows.IsoFile\shell\mount]
"CommandStateSync"=""
"ExplorerCommandHandler"="{9ab3b1c9-3225-4bb4-93b6-bfb3c0d93743}"
"MultiSelectModel"="Document"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Windows.IsoFile\shell\mount\command]
@=hex(2):25,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,52,00,6f,00,6f,00,74,00,25,\
  00,5c,00,45,00,78,00,70,00,6c,00,6f,00,72,00,65,00,72,00,2e,00,65,00,78,00,\
  65,00,00,00
"DelegateExecute"="{9ab3b1c9-3225-4bb4-93b6-bfb3c0d93743}"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Windows.IsoFile\tabsets]
"selection"=dword:00000704

[-HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.iso]

[-HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Roaming\OpenWith\FileExts\.iso]
```

You can also download the same code within a readily available `.reg` file from original source below...

(Source:  [Restore Default File Type Associations in Windows 10](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/8703-restore-default-file-type-associations-windows-10-a.html))

Once the default `.iso` file type association is restored, the accepted answer referenced within the duplicate question should work perfectly.

Comment: Confirmed - 7Zip was associated with .iso.  This script restored the default burner.

Comment: Oh my goodness. If 7-Zip is associated, then disassociate for all users it by running it as Administrator, which reverts it to Windows Explorer, or associate with Windows Explorer for yourself through the standard UI tools. There's no need for registry hacking.

Comment: @Rich  While I appreciate your feedback, I think that labeling the proposed solution "registry hacking" is probably a bit too harsh. It is a method that has been tested at great length, it comes from a very prominent source (Shawn Brink's website), and it works quite well. Also, you will notice from previous comments that the OP didn't mention anything about 7-Zip, and Guy Gordon isn't the OP. While your suggestion will work perfectly for 7-Zip, restoring the default values with a `.reg` file will work for **any** application that inadvertently took control of the `.iso` file type association.

Comment: All good points.  @GuyGordon see my advice to you in the previous comment that I'm getting flamed about.

Comment: @Rich I wasn't trying to *"flame"* you in any way, and I certainly apologize if the message conveyed in that manner. I was simply explaining the logic behind my origiinal answer while trying to emphasize that labeling it "registry hacking" and down-voting it seems to be rather harsh treatment for a solution that repeatedly proven to be reliable.

Comment: I would always downvote a registry hack, no matter the prominence of the source. Pulling rank really wasn't necessary, and only leaves a sour feeling. Equally, since this is a filetype association issue, I would look at the file association first to discover which application wants the association, then look for a way to reverse that. This avoids situations where an update, or a trigger-happy user, might re-establish the unwanted association.

Comment: Doesn't work for me

Comment: @Dims if it *"doesn't work for you,"* there is a fairly good chance that it is a user error.  Perhaps you should actually ask for help, rather than down-vote when you are literally the **only** person who couldn't get it to work... just like you did within [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/902758/remove-or-prevent-sidebar-from-opening-by-default-on-adobe-reader/1173789#1173789).  It worked perfectly for 120 different people, but somehow *you* are the only person that couldn't understand it. Perhaps that's just a big coincidence?

Answer (score 5):

In windows 10 you can simply right click an iso and select to burn it to a disk.

1. Insert a blank CD or DVD in your writable optical drive.
2. Right-click on the ISO file and select "Burn disk image."
3. Select "Verify disc after burning" to make sure the ISO was burned without any errors.
4. Click Burn

Comment: No such option is there, and I was hoping to use a builtin.

Comment: I had a program that associated the .iso to itself. To have the above actions work, I right-clicked and chose "Open with" and then selected "Windows Explorer". I was then able to run the above instructions. No registry hack needed.

Answer (score 1):

PowerISO will do that job greatly for you, that's if you will not want to use the default windows burner. You can get a more detailed steps on [Burning an iso file on DVD using windows 10 using PowerISO](https://www.poweriso.com/tutorials/iso-burner.htm)

Or

You can follow the steps on [How to Burn ISO Files to DVD](https://www.wikihow.com/Burn-ISO-Files-to-DVD) which is default for windows.

I hope this helps.

Comment: This just puts the iso file on the disc, seemingly in an iso container. Not really what I was going for with making a live boot disc.

Comment: what exactly do you mean by making a live boot disc? I thought you wanna create a bootable disk?