# Adobe Acrobat PRO DC hiding side bar

Tags: pdf, adobe-acrobat, sidebar

OK everyone, I have the same old issue that a lot of people have had in the past couple of years.

Hiding the RHS pane and making it stay gone.

I've read through various forum posts and tried different things. I'll list them below:

Firstly, we found when we open a PDF, it will open with the Side bar, if we hide it, then close and re-open, the side bar is open again.
The only time this preference is saved is if the user is a local administrator.

We have Remote Desktop servers so allowing users to have local administrator permissions is a no no.

I've had a look through this forum post
[Remove or prevent sidebar from opening by default on Adobe Reader](https://superuser.com/questions/902758/remove-or-prevent-sidebar-from-opening-by-default-on-adobe-reader/1173789#1173789?newreg=33ea9ce6561041f399af693352fe4932)

Specifically "use the **Menu Bar** to **select Edit > Preferences** and in the subsequent window highlight **Documents** on the upper-left. Check the box to **Remember current state of Tools Pane and then select the OK button**"
For some reason in Adobe Acrobat PRO, this option is **NOT** there.

I then found this
https://superuser.com/a/918966/869409
So i made the changes on our test servers and low and behold, the RHS pane is closed, no matter which document, it's not there. To open the tools back up, all I do is press Tools and it opens.

Great, rolled it out to the live servers and it appeared to work OK.
Until late Friday, one user reported the pane was opening and I've now (Monday) found a majority of users have the pane opening on all documents again.
Except, my account doesn't, it's not an administrator or anything like that, it's just a regular user account.

I'm at a loss as to why it has suddenly started showing up again for people, nothing has changed that I'm aware of.

Had nothing but problems with Adobe DC since updating to it.

open to all suggestions

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

after some further testing it looks like the issue is resolved in one of the later patches. We were running on the base 2015.006.30033 version.

Testing with version 2015.006.30392 showed the pane staying closed re-opening a document.

Comment: Don't forget to mark this the answer