# Reading mode as default view in adobe acrobat dc

Tags: pdf, adobe-acrobat, adobe-reader

How can i make reading mode as default viewing mode in adobe acrobat dc?
I know about the shortcut ctrl+h but i want to open pdf files into reading mode by default. because it is way faster!
I tried checking the settings in my pdf reader but i did not find anything!
is there an option like that in settings or a workaround that i can try?

Comment: Try the following:  Adobe Acrobat, Edit, Preferences, Documents:  Enable (check) Restore last view settings when reopening documents.  There is no reading mode setting for initial document Open that I can see.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's safe to say that you can't just go through the interface. But I found a solution here:

[Remove or prevent sidebar from opening by default on Adobe Reader](https://superuser.com/questions/902758/remove-or-prevent-sidebar-from-opening-by-default-on-adobe-reader)

> Go to the install directory, i.e. C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Acrobat Reader DC\Reader\AcroApp\ENU
> Create a new subfolder (I used Disabled).
> Move three files from the ENU folder into the new Disabled folder: >AppCenter_R.aapp, Home.aapp and Viewer.aapp.
> Open a PDF and no more Tool Pane!

In my case the installation directory was : "C:\Program Files\Adobe\Acrobat DC\AcrobatRdrApp\ENU"

I don't really know what I do so do it with caution, but it worked well for me.